# Quartz Drawing While Scrolling Issue

Tags: uiview, uiscrollview, quartz-graphics, drawrect

I have a subclass of UIView which I draw a graph on it.

**GraphingView.h**

```
@interface GraphingView : UIView
...
@end
```

I draw things here:

**GraphingView.m**

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
...
}
```

Then, from another controller, I call this graph by just initializing and add that subview

```
graphView = [[GraphingView alloc] init];
...
[self.view addSubview:graphView];
```

But I actually call this subview multiple times with UIScrollView in different pages. Let's say 3 pages for 3 different graphs. Everything works fine if I just need 3 static graphs. Because of my scroller is infinite, every time I swipe the scroller left or right, the scroller will generate an older or newer graph which sits previous or next to the graph of direction. For that reason, I use `scrollViewDidScroll` to detect and insert new graph. However, `scrollViewDidScroll` makes too many calls to the subviews since it has not been stopped. So, that means I am re-drawing too much with Quartz 2D and it causes the app to crash. Does that sounds memory leak of Quartz?

For that matter, I then decided to call the graph subview in `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` instead. But after a while scrolling, the app crashes just like above since I still call the subview which has drawRect method too many times.

**My question is, how do I prevent this Quartz from crashing because `drawRect` is being called more than it should be?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The memory leak is caused by sqlite3 actually because I query data in every graph view.

There is an outstanding article for those who deals with memory leak which I highly recommend [When is a Leak not a Leak? Using Heapshot Analysis to Find Undesirable Memory Growth](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/)